# repeating-linear-gradient spacing becomes out-of-sync

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to use [`repeating-linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient) to zebra-stripe a code block. To that end, I specified an explicit `line-height` in the code block and alternated the color at intervals of that value.

It works great for a few lines, but the text and stripes eventually stop lining up. Does anyone know why this is and whether it can be fixed?

```css
pre {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
  to bottom,
  transparent 0,
  transparent 1.4em,
  #ddd 1.4em,
  #ddd 2.8em);
}
```

```html
<pre>Here
I
will
write
many
lines
of
text
and
the
spacing
starts
out
quite
well
but
eventually
the
lines
and
stripes
get
messed
up
and
this
makes
me
sad.</pre>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height):

> On a block container element whose content is composed of inline-level
>   elements, 'line-height' specifies the minimal height of line boxes
>   within the element.

The keyword here being "**minimal**". If the font-size is large enough it will increase the spacing of your lines to more than your defined line-height.

To illustrate, here is your snippet with a smaller font-size:

```css
pre {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
  to bottom,
  transparent 0,
  transparent 1.4em,
  #ddd 1.4em,
  #ddd 2.8em);
}
```

```html
<pre>Here
I
will
write
many
lines
of
text
and
the
spacing
starts
out
quite
well
and
the
lines
and
stripes
don't
ever 
get
messed
up
and
this
makes
me
happy. :-)</pre>
```

Or here with a larger line-height:

```css
pre {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 2em;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
  to bottom,
  transparent 0,
  transparent 2em,
  #ddd 2em,
  #ddd 4em);
}
```

```html
<pre>Here
I
will
write
many
lines
of
text
and
the
spacing
starts
out
quite
well
and
the
lines
and
stripes
don't
ever 
get
messed
up
and
this
makes
me
happy. :-)</pre>
```